# Tomcat throws status 500 and NullPointer when Jersey REST resource is accessed

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, jersey-2.0

I have a very simple Resource class that looks like below

```
package service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("names")
public class NameService {


    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("name")
    @GET
    public String getName(@QueryParam(value="id")int id){
        return "Nishanth";
    }



}
```

I defined a custom application class ( extending ResourceConfig) to encapsulate this Resource class.

```
package application;


import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig{

    public MyApp()
    {
        packages("service");
    }

}
```

My web.xml looks like below. This is a servlet 3.0 web application in Eclipse meant to be deployed on Tomcat 7

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>RESTapp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>application.MyApp</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application.MyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/res/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My lib has the below jars added to application classpath.

[image: Jar dependencies]

I deploy the above application directly through Eclipse into a Tomcat 7.0 servlet container. I access the below URL

http://localhost:8080/RESTapp/res/names/name?id=2

and the browser shows the error below with response status 500

```
HTTP Status 500 - 


type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1641)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 logs.
```

I know that the above error is thrown when the container is not able to find a servlet-class. I could be wrong.
Not sure what is going wrong here since as per Jersey API docs, Jersey container should add the servlet class when deployed this way in a Servlet 3.0 container.

I checked all over stack overflow and other forum posts but i could not find anything close to the issue i am facing now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is something you are not showing us, otherwise your code would not compile. The `ResourceConfig` class you are using is a Jersey 2.x class (you can tell be `org.glassfish.jersey`). All your jars are Jersey 1.x. The two are not compatible. I don't know how your code is compiling, as I don't see any Jersey 2x. jars in your list. For Jersey 1.x instead you should extend `PackagesResourceConfig`. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e188). Make sure to get rid of all your Jersey 2.x jars if you have any and that the package you are using is `com.sun.jersey`

Comment: If you want to use Jersey 2.x, then get rid of everything you have, and add all the jars from the [JAX-RS RI Bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). Note that the bundle doesn't come with any JSON support. You will need to add some jars that do not come with the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I apologize. I had placed the wrong image. Please see the updated dependency list. I am using 2x jars. Upvoting you for pointing that out.

Comment: I would check that the jars are actually getting deployed with the app. This is a problem I see a lot with Eclipse/Tomcat users. Also those are not all the jars from the distribution. There are other jars you should also include. You may also want to try the web.xml configuration where you declare Jersey servlet class. At least this way, if the jars aren't getting deployed, you will get a ClassNotFoundException. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2)

Comment: The whole point of this exercise was to see if the auto addition of the servlet by the Jersey Container. Adding a web.xml configuration works perfectly but since the Jersey specs explicitly mentions that the container would add the servlet if absent, i reckoned it should work if i tried as well.